# How can show array items in combobox

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array in java class, and i want to show all array items in jcombobox. I have some experience in c# and I have tryed do something similar, in relation to c#, with a for cycle but something is wrong in my code. At moment I do not have computer with me, so I can`t post any code here to see and analyse my work.

How can I create a method to show all array items when he is called by the correct jcomboboxevent

Comment: show us what you have coded so far plz

Comment: if you look at the javadoc there is a constructor that takes in a [`Vector<E>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#JComboBox-java.util.Vector-) or an [`E[]`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#JComboBox-E:A-) where you can pass in your array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
for arraylists do this,

```
Whatever type[] obj = arraylist.toArray(new whatever type[arraylist.size()]);
    JComboBox<?> combo = new JComboBox<>(obj);
```

For arrays do this:

```
JComboBox<?> combo = new JComboBox<>(array);
```